# doxygen add subpage to tableofcontents

Tags: markdown, doxygen, tableofcontents

in my doxygen documentation for HTML I have some subpages (@subpage) that I'd like to be included in my table of content (@tableofcontents).

For now, I have

```
@section secname NameOfSection
@subpage pname "NameOfSection"
```

but I'd like to have the section as a link to the subpage. I also tried

```
@section secname @subpage NameOfSection "NameOfSection"
```

or

```
@section secname @link https://...
```

before but it didn't work.

is there a way to achieve this?

thank you

P.S: here is a small example, generated output included https://www.dropbox.com/s/0etlgnml3qhfi89/doxy.zip?dl=0

P.P.S: no login needed for download

Comment: Which version of doxygen? I did not test but why using section and subpage and not page and subpage?

Comment: I am using doxygen 1.8.11 but that should not matter. 
Yes I am using pages and subpages. In fact the above description corresponds to the content of a page. The problem is page and subpage do not appear in tableofcontents.

Comment: Please try with 1.8.14 and provide (when problem is persistent) a small example.

Comment: I checked if subsection could be used instead of subpage but the documentation states: \n\n<br>

This command only works inside a section of a related page documentation block and not in other documentation blocks!

\n\n</br> so this won't work eighter

Comment: how can I add a small example in stackoverflow?

Comment: I was successful when having: page and within it a section and within this a subsection. Regarding example paste the example like you did with the code parts in the question.

Comment: I ended up creating a complete doxygen example for download. It is important to me having the "subsection" parts in a separate file. Also, I did not update doxygen since it doesn't matter. It's not a bug or something.

Comment: I don't think theer is a solution, as far as I understand, you want to have the tableofcontents having information from multiple files and according to the doxygen documentation this is not possible: \tableofcontents
Creates a table of contents at the top of a page, listing all sections and subsections in the page.
Warning
This command only works inside related page documentation and not in other documentation blocks and only
has effect in the HTML output! 

Maybe have a look at GENERATE_TREEVIEW as well?

Comment: I started NOT to use GENERATE_TREEVIEW long ago since I don't really like the outcome. In terms of functionality it certainly does what I want to achieve. Out of possible solutions I consider using GENERATE_TREEVIEW as the best. Thank you